# how to carry a specific number of significant figures while computing?

Tags: c#, c++

How to carry more or less than six significant figures (4 , 5 , 7.. ) in the computation while running a program ?
i'm writing a program to solve a system of linear equations /using Gauss elimination method in the following example / . and i want to consider the relative errors happening , in this example , the result is very sensitive to the number of significant figures carried in the computation .
[image: significant figures]

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your example. Which value is computed, by what calculation, what would be the error-free result?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to determine the relative or absolute errors for a computation which is too complex to be estimated manually, you could try using [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). This approach will help you to trace the error in each of your variables throughout the calculation process. Of course, you will typically have to implement something like Gauss elimination by yourself, since it will be unlikely to find a ready-made implementation using interval arithmetic for your requirements.

Try googling for "interval arithmetic [you favorite language]" to find a suitable library.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into [Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

> In computer science, arbitrary-precision arithmetic, ... , indicates that calculations are performed on numbers whose digits of precision are limited only by the available memory of the host system.

Using arbitrary precision should allow you to specify enough significant digits to resolve the calculation you're having problems with.

And have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729421/1345223) for additional guidance on how to do that within C#.